# Laravel two diffrent middleware authentication from auth middleware only

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4, laravel-middleware

I have two seprate table for authentication. Following middleware pointing to different table:

```
$this->middleware('auth:admin'); // - admins 
$this->middleware('auth'); // - user
```

The solution i need :

- I want authentication must be done with two diffrent table through only 
    "`$this->middleware('auth')`" middleware
- Through middleware "`$this->middleware('auth')`" I want to login both 
     admin and user. Currently admin and user login from diffrent 
     middleware I have shown above.

For this, in which file and where I need to change in my project folder?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have both "guards" be checked you can just pass multiple guards to the `auth` middleware.

```
$this->middleware('auth:web,admin');
```

This will spin through the guards passed and if any of them produce a user it will set that guard as the default moving forward.

Comment: Thank you @lagbox,This solution is working properly and accurately.Great Work #lagbox.Thanks for the help.Thank you.